# How to open image in Paint by clicking on image in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, images, microsoft-paint

With my old laptop on Windows 10, I could double click on any picture in a word file and it would open it in Paint for editing.

With new laptop, double clicking on an image in word is not doing anything.

What settings do I need to change to easily open image in Paint for editing.

Comment: Which office version where you using on your old laptop? Installing that same version of office on new laptop will help.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such feature in newer version of Word. Is it in Paint?  In earlier Word, we can edit photos with Picture Manager. [Picture Manager](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/where-is-picture-manager-58837c3e-34db-4904-95e8-4eca7b7c5730) is not included with Office 2013 and later versions, but you can install it as a standalone app. If it's not Picture Manager, it seems that you used some specific add-ins or other tools to do this. You can provide the information about your old Office to help us better analyze the problem for you.

Comment: @HerbGu I thought that it's feature of Word alone and no additional software(such as Picture Manager) was involved - I can be wrong. Old Laptop belonged to Old Company so I wont be able to get info on MS Office of that laptop. :(